# List of objects with corresponding controls (views) in Android

Tags: java, android, xml, user-interface, mobile

I'm having problems grasping a concept. I'm making an app where i will have an array of custom objects. These object should then be represented in a Layout.

Simplifying here to make the point come across:

Lets say I have a list of MyProducts:

```
public class MyProduct {
    private string m_name;
    private float m_price;
    private int m_amount;

    public string getName() {
        return name;
    }
    public void setName(string name) {
        m_name = name;
    }

    etc...
}
```

And then I want a compound view(?) displaying this information - and also allowing me to set some of it. Like a box with a TextView of the name, price and amount etc.

So when a change is made in one of the controls the object in the list should be updated. How would I actually do that?

My spontaneous idea would be to implement all the logic directly in the custom view. So that MyProduct extends let's say LinearLayout. Then all the logic I want for my objects is implemented directly in there. And the view will implement implements View.OnClickListener and take care of all it's changes.

Something like this:

```
public class MyProduct extends LinearLayout {
    private TextView m_nameTextView;
    private EditText m_priceEditText;
    private Spinner m_amountSpinner;

    private string m_name;
    private float m_price;
    private int m_amount;

    public ExerciseView(Context context, AttributeSet attrs) {
        super(context, attrs); 

        LayoutInflater inflater = (LayoutInflater) context.getSystemService(Context.LAYOUT_INFLATER_SERVICE);
        inflater.inflate(R.layout.MyProduct, this);

        m_nameTextView = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.name);
        m_priceEditText = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.price);
        m_amountSpinner = (Spinner) findViewById(R.id.amount);

    }

    public string getName() {
        return name;
    }
    public void setName(string name) {
        m_name = name;
    }

    etc..
}
```

Is that kosher? 
Am I thinking all wrong?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The functionality you're looking for is a ListView with a custom adapter.

This is a good tutorial: http://www.vogella.com/tutorials/AndroidListView/article.html

Comment: let's say I want to make every item have a bunch of controls. And I want to interact with the corresponding datamodel directly. Is that possible/simple with this solution?

Comment: Yes, that's exactly what it is for.

Comment: Thank you. I actually ended up building a complex compound view class instead. It's a bit closer to what I need. Marking this as accepted answer anyway since it's probably what anyone with my initial question would need.